# Returning the product of a list

Tags: python

Is there a more concise, efficient or simply pythonic way to do the following?

```
def product(lst):
    p = 1
    for i in lst:
        p *= i
    return p
```

---

After some tests I have found out that this is marginally faster than using `operator.mul`:

```
from operator import mul
# from functools import reduce # python3 compatibility

def with_lambda(lst):
    reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, lst)

def without_lambda(lst):
    reduce(mul, lst)

def forloop(lst):
    r = 1
    for x in lst:
        r *= x
    return r

import timeit

a = range(50)
b = range(1,50)#no zero
t = timeit.Timer("with_lambda(a)", "from __main__ import with_lambda,a")
print("with lambda:", t.timeit())
t = timeit.Timer("without_lambda(a)", "from __main__ import without_lambda,a")
print("without lambda:", t.timeit())
t = timeit.Timer("forloop(a)", "from __main__ import forloop,a")
print("for loop:", t.timeit())

t = timeit.Timer("with_lambda(b)", "from __main__ import with_lambda,b")
print("with lambda (no 0):", t.timeit())
t = timeit.Timer("without_lambda(b)", "from __main__ import without_lambda,b")
print("without lambda (no 0):", t.timeit())
t = timeit.Timer("forloop(b)", "from __main__ import forloop,b")
print("for loop (no 0):", t.timeit())
```

gives me

```
('with lambda:', 17.755449056625366)
('without lambda:', 8.2084708213806152)
('for loop:', 7.4836349487304688)
('with lambda (no 0):', 22.570688009262085)
('without lambda (no 0):', 12.472226858139038)
('for loop (no 0):', 11.04065990447998)
```

Comment: The with-zero results are not very interesting. What would be interesting is what version of Python you are using on what platform.

Comment: No - I just added the without zero because I realised that wiso's answer included zeroes and I wondered how much difference it made.
I am using python 2.6.4 on ubuntu 9.10.

Comment: There's a functional difference between the options given here in that for an empty list the `reduce` answers raise a `TypeError`, whereas the `for` loop answer returns 1. This is a bug in the `for` loop answer (the product of an empty list is no more 1 than it is 17 or 'armadillo').

Comment: Please try to avoid using names of built-ins (such as list) for the names of your variables.

Comment: Old answer, but I am tempted to edit so it doesn't use `list` as a variable name...

Comment: The product of an empty list is 1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product

Comment: @ScottGriffiths Would you also make the claim that the sum of an empty list is not 0? I strongly disagree with your claim, the product of an empty list is 1.

Comment: @semicolon: It depends on the type of the elements that aren't in the empty list (i.e. it's not well defined). The sum of the list `['a', 'b', 'c']` is the string `'abc'`, so you can argue equally well that the sum of the empty list should be `''` (an empty string). So a `TypeError` seems appropriate to me - the Python language does seem to agree with me here...

Comment: @ScottGriffiths I should have specified that I meant a list of numbers. And I would say that the sum of an empty list is the identity element of `+` for that type of list (likewise for product / `*`). Now I realize that Python is dynamically typed which makes things harder, but this is a solved problem in sane languages with static type systems like Haskell. But `Python` only allows `sum` to work on numbers anyway, since `sum(['a', 'b'])` doesn't even work, so I again say that `0` makes sense for `sum` and `1` for product.

Comment: @semicolon: I was doing the summation in the style of the OP: `reduce(add, ['a', 'b', 'c'])` which does work (and you can also try just `'a' + 'b'`). The built-in `sum` is *defined* to only work for numbers, so yes if you assume the type of the items that aren't in the list you can sum the empty list. But you could also sum a list using a method that only works for strings: `'a' + 'b' + 'c'` can be done as `''.join(['a', 'b', 'c'])` in the same way as `1 + 2 + 3` can be done as `sum([1, 2, 3])`, but in this case summing an empty list will give an empty string, not zero.

Comment: @ScottGriffiths I did acknowledge that in Python things are more complicated due to it lacking a type system, so I guess having it fail for empty lists is just one penalty you pay for not having static types. In Haskell this is a solved problem with things like `mempty`, `empty`, and the fact that `1` and `0` are polymorphic. I was more arguing that "mathematically" the product of an empty list is `1`, or rather "the multiplicative identity of that element", even if for practical purposes something like a `TypeError` or requiring a starting value might be necessary, in Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I multiply all items in a list together with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840379/how-can-i-multiply-all-items-in-a-list-together-with-python)

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Without using lambda:

```
from operator import mul
# from functools import reduce # python3 compatibility
reduce(mul, list, 1)
```

it is better and faster. With python 2.7.5

```
from operator import mul
import numpy as np
import numexpr as ne
# from functools import reduce # python3 compatibility

a = range(1, 101)
%timeit reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, a)   # (1)
%timeit reduce(mul, a)                  # (2)
%timeit np.prod(a)                      # (3)
%timeit ne.evaluate("prod(a)")          # (4)
```

In the following configuration:

```
a = range(1, 101)  # A
a = np.array(a)    # B
a = np.arange(1, 1e4, dtype=int) #C
a = np.arange(1, 1e5, dtype=float) #D
```

Results with python 2.7.5

```
       |     1     |     2     |     3     |     4     |
-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
 A       20.8 µs     13.3 µs     22.6 µs     39.6 µs     
 B        106 µs     95.3 µs     5.92 µs     26.1 µs
 C       4.34 ms     3.51 ms     16.7 µs     38.9 µs
 D       46.6 ms     38.5 ms      180 µs      216 µs
```

Result: `np.prod` is the fastest one, if you use `np.array` as data structure (18x for small array, 250x for large array)

with python 3.3.2:

```
       |     1     |     2     |     3     |     4     |
-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
 A       23.6 µs     12.3 µs     68.6 µs     84.9 µs     
 B        133 µs      107 µs     7.42 µs     27.5 µs
 C       4.79 ms     3.74 ms     18.6 µs     40.9 µs
 D       48.4 ms     36.8 ms      187 µs      214 µs
```

Is python 3 slower?

Comment: Very interesting, thanks.  Any idea why python 3 might be slower?

Comment: Possible reasons: (1) Python 3 `int` is Python 2 `long`. Python 2 will be using "int" until it overflows 32 bits; Python 3 will use "long" from the start. (2) Python 3.0 was a "proof of concept". Upgrade to 3.1 ASAP!

Comment: I've redone the same test on an other machine:

python 2.6
('with lambda:', 21.843887090682983)     
('without lambda:', 9.7096879482269287)
python 3.1:
with lambda: 24.7712180614
without lambda: 10.7758350372

Comment: both fail with empty lists.

Comment: @RuggeroTurra Theory: As time passes the speed of Python 3.x will improve. Proof: Your profile times.

Comment: `reduce(mul, list)` fails if list is empty...how about `return reduce(mul, list) if list else 1` instead?

Comment: I tried using numpy `prod(list(range(5,101)))` and it yields `0`, why is that? Can anyone reproduce this result? This is Python 3 installed using Anaconda.

Comment: it is due to overflow, try `np.prod(range(1, 66)) * 66`. To solve it use `np.prod(np.arange(1L, 101L, dtype=np.object))`

Comment: Note that you must import the `reduce` operator from the `functools` module in Python 3.  I.E. `from functools import reduce`.

Answer (score 90):

Starting `Python 3.8`, a [`prod`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html#math.prod) function has been included to the `math` module in the standard library:

> math.prod(iterable, *, start=1)

which returns the product of a `start` value (default: 1) times an iterable of numbers:

```
import math

math.prod([2, 3, 4]) # 24
```

Note that if the iterable is empty, this will produce `1` (or the `start` value if provided).

Answer (score 61):

```py
from functools import reduce

a = [1, 2, 3]
reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, a, 1)
```

Comment: +1 but see @wiso's answer about `operator.mul` for a better way to do it.

Comment: why is operator.mul preferrable to x*y?

Comment: operator.mul is a function and would thus be a replacement not only for x*y but for the entire lambda expression (i.e. the first argument to `reduce`)

Comment: You have to do an import  `from functools import reduce` to make it work in Python 3.

Answer (score 53):

if you just have numbers in your list:

```
from numpy import prod
prod(list)
```

*EDIT*: as pointed out by @off99555 this does not work for large integer results in which case it returns a result of type `numpy.int64` while Ian Clelland's solution based on `operator.mul` and `reduce` works for large integer results because it returns `long`.

Comment: this is slower if the list is short

Comment: I tried evaluating `from numpy import prod; prod(list(range(5,101)))` and it outputted `0`, can you reproduce this result on Python 3?

Comment: because `prod` returns a result of type `numpy.int64` in this case and you get an overflow (a negative value actually) already for `range(5,23)`. Use @Ian Clelland's solution based on `operator.mul` and `reduce` for large integers (it returns a `long` in this case which seems to have arbitrary precision).

Comment: @off99555 Two solutions: either start with a float type list by doing `np.prod(np.arange(5.0,101.0))` or convert it to float by doing `np.prod(np.array(range(5,101)).astype(np.float64))`. Note that NumPy uses `np.float64` instead of `float`. I don't know the difference.

Answer (score 27):

Well if you really wanted to make it one line without importing anything you could do:

```
eval('*'.join(str(item) for item in list))
```

But don't.

Comment: Quite Pythonic in essence

Comment: ty for the sol without importing anything!

Answer (score 23):

I've tested various solutions with [perfplot](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot) (a small project of mine) and found that

```py
numpy.prod(lst)
```

is *by far* the fastest solution (if the list isn't very short).

[image]

---

Code to reproduce the plot:

```py
import perfplot
import numpy

import math
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce

from itertools import accumulate


def reduce_lambda(lst):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, lst)


def reduce_mul(lst):
    return reduce(mul, lst)


def forloop(lst):
    r = 1
    for x in lst:
        r *= x
    return r


def numpy_prod(lst):
    return numpy.prod(lst)


def math_prod(lst):
    return math.prod(lst)


def itertools_accumulate(lst):
    for value in accumulate(lst, mul):
        pass
    return value


b = perfplot.bench(
    setup=numpy.random.rand,
    kernels=[
        reduce_lambda,
        reduce_mul,
        forloop,
        numpy_prod,
        itertools_accumulate,
        math_prod,
    ],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(20)],
    xlabel="len(a)",
)
b.save("out.png")
b.show()
```

Answer (score 19):

I remember some long discussions on comp.lang.python (sorry, too lazy to produce pointers now) which concluded that **your original `product()` definition is the most Pythonic**.

Note that the proposal is not to write a for loop every time you want to do it, but to write a function once (per type of reduction) and call it as needed!  Calling reduction functions is very Pythonic - it works sweetly with generator expressions, and since the sucessful introduction of `sum()`, Python keeps growing more and more builtin reduction functions - `any()` and `all()` are the latest additions...

This conclusion is kinda official - `reduce()` was [removed](http://docs.python.org/dev/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins) from builtins in Python 3.0, saying:

> "Use `functools.reduce()` if you really need it; however, 99 percent of the time an explicit for loop is more readable."

See also [The fate of reduce() in Python 3000](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/587) for a supporting quote from Guido (and some less supporting comments by Lispers that read that blog).

P.S. if by chance you need `product()` for combinatorics, see [`math.factorial()`](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.factorial) (new 2.6).

Comment: +1 for an accurate (to the best of my knowledge) account of the prevailing moods in the Python community -- while I definately prefer going against said prevailing moods in this case, it's best to know them for what they are anyway. Also, I like the bit about unsupportive Lispers from LtU (I'd be one of those, I guess). :-)

Answer (score 18):

```
import operator
reduce(operator.mul, list, 1)
```

Comment: is the last argument (1) really necessary?

Comment: The last argument is necessary if the list may be empty, otherwise it will throw a TypeError exception.  Of course, sometimes an exception will be what you want.

Comment: For me it returns 0 without that argument, so you can also consider it necessary to enforce the empty product convention.

Comment: or `functools.reduce(..)` in [python3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13638960/288875)

Answer (score 7):

The intent of this answer is to provide a calculation that is useful in certain circumstances -- namely when a) there are a large number of values being multiplied such that the final product may be extremely large or extremely small, and b) you don't really care about the exact answer, but instead have a number of sequences, and want to be able to order them based on each one's product.

If you want to multiply the elements of a list, where l is the list, you can do:

```
import math
math.exp(sum(map(math.log, l)))
```

Now, that approach is not as readable as

```
from operator import mul
reduce(mul, list)
```

If you're a mathematician who isn't familiar with reduce() the opposite might be true, but I wouldn't advise using it under normal circumstances. It's also less readable than the product() function mentioned in the question (at least to non-mathematicians).

However, if you're ever in a situation where you risk underflow or overflow, such as in

```
>>> reduce(mul, [10.]*309)
inf
```

and your purpose is to compare the products of different sequences rather than to know what the products are, then

```
>>> sum(map(math.log, [10.]*309))
711.49879373515785
```

is the way to go because it's virtually impossible to have a real-world problem in which you would overflow or underflow with this approach. (The larger the result of that calculation is, the larger the product would be if you *could* calculate it.)

Comment: It's clever, but fails if you have any negative or zero values. :/

Answer (score 3):

I am surprised no-one has suggested using `itertools.accumulate` with `operator.mul`. This avoids using `reduce`, which is different for Python 2 and 3 (due to the `functools` import required for Python 3), and moreover is considered un-pythonic [by Guido van Rossum himself](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196):

```
from itertools import accumulate
from operator import mul

def prod(lst):
    for value in accumulate(lst, mul):
        pass
    return value
```

Example:

```
prod([1,5,4,3,5,6])
# 1800
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use [`numba`](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/5minguide.html) and the [`@jit` or `@njit` decorator](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/jit.html). I also made one or two little tweaks to your code (at least in Python 3, "list" is a keyword that shouldn't be used for a variable name):

```
@njit
def njit_product(lst):
    p = lst[0]  # first element
    for i in lst[1:]:  # loop over remaining elements
        p *= i
    return p
```

For timing purposes, you need to run once to compile the function first using numba. In general, the function will be compiled the first time it is called, and then called from memory after that (faster).

```
njit_product([1, 2])  # execute once to compile
```

Now when you execute your code, it will run with the compiled version of the function. I timed them using a Jupyter notebook and the `%timeit` magic function:

```
product(b)  # yours
# 32.7 µs ± 510 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

njit_product(b)
# 92.9 µs ± 392 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Note that on my machine, running Python 3.5, the native Python `for` loop was actually the fastest. There may be a trick here when it comes to measuring numba-decorated performance with Jupyter notebooks and the `%timeit` magic function. I am not sure that the timings above are correct, so I recommend trying it out on your system and seeing if numba gives you a performance boost.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way I found was, using while:

```
mysetup = '''
import numpy as np
from find_intervals import return_intersections 
'''

# code snippet whose execution time is to be measured
mycode = '''

x = [4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
prod = 1
i = 0
while True:
    prod = prod * x[i]
    i = i + 1
    if i == len(x):
        break
'''

# timeit statement for while:
print("using while : ",
timeit.timeit(setup=mysetup,
              stmt=mycode))

# timeit statement for mul:
print("using mul : ",
    timeit.timeit('from functools import reduce;
    from operator import mul;
    c = reduce(mul, [4,5,6,7,8,9,10])'))

# timeit statement for mul:
print("using lambda : ",      
    timeit.timeit('from functools import reduce;
    from operator import mul;
    c = reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, [4,5,6,7,8,9,10])'))
```

and the timings are:

```
>>> using while : 0.8887967770060641

>>> using mul : 2.0838719510065857

>>> using lambda : 2.4227715369997895
```

Comment: This is likely due the short length of the list, some more experimentation is likely needed

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 result for the OP's tests: (best of 3 for each)

```
with lambda: 18.978000981995137
without lambda: 8.110567473006085
for loop: 10.795806062000338
with lambda (no 0): 26.612515013999655
without lambda (no 0): 14.704098362999503
for loop (no 0): 14.93075215499266
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure about the fastest way, but here is the short code to get product of any collection without importing any library or module.

```
eval('*'.join(map(str,l)))
```

Comment: That’s definitely the slowest way. Also it won’t work properly with `Decimal` and other numeric types which don’t roundtrip through `str()`.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the code:

```
product = 1 # Set product to 1 because when you multiply it you don't want you answer to always be 0
my_list = list(input("Type in a list: ").split(", ")) # When input, the data is a string, so you need to convert it into a list and split it to make it a list.
for i in range(0, len(my_list)):
  product *= int(my_list[i])
print("The product of all elements in your list is: ", product)
```

Answer (score -6):

This also works though its cheating

```
def factorial(n):
    x=[]
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    else:
        for i in range(1,n+1): 
            p*=i
            x.append(p)
        print x[n-1]
```

Comment: I've fixed the indentation, but I think you should replace the last `print` with a return. Also, there's no need to store the intermediate values in a list, you just need to store `p` betweens iterations.