# Product of a list python

Tags: python, python-3.x, product

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Returning the product of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104782/returning-the-product-of-a-list)

Is there any other way to get the product of a list, than this way:

```
def prod(L):
 p=1
 for i in L:
   p= i * p
 return p
```

This code is correct, but I need to find another way to do it. And I really can't find it.

Comment: Checked that question... and I'm not sure is not duplicate, but I didn't found the answer I need there.

Comment: @jamylak I tried it a couple of times and the output was correct.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using [`reduce(f, iterable[, initializer])`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reduce):

```
>>> from operator import mul
>>> reduce(mul, [1, 2, 3], 1)
6
```

`reduce()` abstracts over the following pattern:
`a ⊗ b ⊗ c ⊗ d ⊗ e ...` where `⊗` is a binary (left associative) operator, i.e. a function accepting two parameters.

Comment: This won't work with empty list.

Comment: @Dogbert Yes it will, because an initializer is given.

Comment: Just noting that the question is tagged "python-3.x", and in Python 3 the `reduce` function is not a built-in. Rather, it's in the `functools` module.

Comment: @phant0m there wasn't this initializer yet, when the Dogbert wrote his comment.

Comment: Ah yes, I see that now. In that case, I recommend that you yourself had replied to the comment, so future visitors see that the mistake has been fixed.

Answer (score 10):

If you're allowed to use `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
product = np.product([1, 2, 3]) # returns 1.0 if empty list
```

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, [1, 2, 3], 1)
6
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, [], 1)
1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def prod(array):
    if len(array)==0: return 1
    else: return array[0]*prod(array[1:])
```