# How can I multiply numbers in a list (after removing duplicates)?

Tags: python

I'm using Python 3.2.3 IDLE. I see some people using the reduce commmand but for some reason I don't have it. Like the code doesn't come up in purple and it recognizes reduce as a variable.

Here's part of my code:

```
numbers = [10, 11, 11]
numbertotal = (set(numbers))
#removes duplicates in my list, therefore, the list only contains [10, 11]
print ("The sum of the list is", (sum(numbertotal))) #sum is 21
print ("The product of the list is" #need help here, basically it should be 10 * 11 = 110
```

I basically want to multiply the list after I remove the duplicates in `numbertotal`.

Comment: Lots of information about getting the product of a list here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104782/returning-the-product-of-a-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `reduce` hides in:

```
from functools import reduce

print("The product of the list is", reduce(lambda x,y:x*y, numbertotal))
```

or

```
from functools import reduce
import operator as op

print("The product of the list is", reduce(op.mul, numbertotal))
```

In python3 it has been moved to `functools`. [The `2to3` handles this case](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/2to3.html?highlight=reduce#2to3fixer-reduce).

Comment: oh okay. i think i got the command running but it didn't work with my code :(

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
product = 1
for j in numbertotal:
    product = product * j
print 'The product of the list is', product
```