# How can I multiply all items in a list together with Python?

Tags: python, list, multiplication

Given a list of numbers like `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`, how can I write code to multiply them all together, i.e. compute `1*2*3*4*5*6`?

Answer (score 260):

**Python 3**: use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
720
```

**Python 2**: use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#reduce):

```
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
720
```

For compatible with 2 and 3 use [Six](https://six.readthedocs.io/#module-six.moves) (`pip install six`), then:

```
>>> from six.moves import reduce
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, [1,2,3,4,5,6])
720
```

Comment: You don't import operator, so this solution is a bit more compact. I wonder which is faster.

Comment: @jheld: I timed product-ing the numbers from 1 to 100. In both python2 and 3, `lambda` took an average of .02s/1000 repetitions, whereas `operator.mul` took an average of .009s/1000 repetitions, making `operator.mul` an order of magnitude faster.

Comment: @whereswalden Any idea as to why?

Comment: @wordsforthewise probably it's that going through an extra function (lambda) adds overhead, whereas `operator.mul` goes straight to C.

Comment: I really wouldn't call .009 an order of magnitude lower than .02. It's just about half.

Comment: As of Python 3.8, it can be simply done with `math.prod([1,2,3,4,5,6])`. (requires import of-course)

Comment: You don't need to install `six` to use the same syntax in Python 2.6 or 2.7 as in Python 3. You just need to use the same line `from functools import reduce` as used in Python 3.

Answer (score 196):

You can use:

```
import operator
import functools
functools.reduce(operator.mul, [1,2,3,4,5,6], 1)
```

See [`reduce`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) and [`operator.mul`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.mul) documentations for an explanation.

You need the `import functools` line in Python 3+.

Comment: Note that in python3, the `reduce()` function has been removed from the global namespace and placed in the `functools` module. So in python3 you need to say `from functools import reduce`.

Comment: The '1' as the third argument is unnecessary here, what's a case where it would be needed?

Comment: @wordsforthewise without the third argument, it throws a TypeError exception if you pass it an empty sequence

Answer (score 121):

I would use the [`numpy.prod`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html) to perform the task:

```
import numpy as np

mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
result = np.prod(np.array(mylist))
```

Comment: Convenient if you're already using Numpy.  You probably don't even need to cast it as a list first, this should work for most cases `result = np.prod(mylist)`

Comment: Two things to watch out for:
 **1)** It might overflow, especially if using the default `numpy.int32` as above
 **2)** For small lists this will be significantly slower, since NumPy needs to allocate an array (relevant if repeated often)

Comment: overflow for values above 21 here ``np.prod(np.array(range(1,21)))``

Comment: It is not a good choice. It can overflow and it is slower. try `reduce`.

Answer (score 80):

If you want to avoid importing anything and avoid more complex areas of Python, you can use a simple for loop:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3]

product = 1  # Don't use 0 here, otherwise, you'll get zero 
             # because anything times zero will be zero.
for num in nums:
    product *= num
```

Comment: Minor note: Slices in Python are very easy, and since we're only dealing with primitives here, you can avoid the minor kludge of starting with 1 by starting with list[0] and iterating over list[1:]. Though getting comfortable with the more functional 'reduce' answers here is valuable in the long term as it's also useful in other circumstances.

Comment: @kungphu The empty product is usually defined as 1, your solution would throw an IndexError exception instead if you pass it an empty sequence

Comment: @Francisco Granted, but this function probably _should_ throw some flavor of exception in that case, since an empty sequence would be invalid input for this function. In fact, this function is not meaningful for any sequence with less than two values; if you pass a sequence with one value and multiply it by 1, you've essentially added a value that wasn't there, which I'd say amounts to unexpected behavior.

Comment: @kungphu, the behaviour for this answer is correct, i.e. passing a list of length 1 returns the value, and passing a list of length 0 returns 1. It's in the same line of thinking that gives sum([]) as 0 or sum([3]) as 3.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product

Comment: I see your point regarding mathematical functions. However, in a practical development situation, I would call it a very rare situation where a function that's explicitly intended to operate on input _should_ return a value given what amounts to no input or invalid input. I suppose it depends on the goal of the exercise: If it's just to replicate the standard library, OK, perhaps it teaches people something about how the (or a) language is or can be implemented. Otherwise I'd say it misses out on a good opportunity to provide a lesson on valid and invalid arguments.

Answer (score 75):

In `Python 3.8` and up, the `math` standard library module provides [`.prod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.prod) for this purpose:

> `math.prod(iterable, *, start=1)`

The method returns the product of a `start` value (default: 1) times an iterable of numbers:

```py
import math
math.prod([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
# 720
```

If the iterable is empty, this will produce `1` (or the `start` value, if provided).

Answer (score 16):

Here's some performance measurements from my machine. Relevant in case this is performed for small inputs in a long-running loop:

```
import functools, operator, timeit
import numpy as np

def multiply_numpy(iterable):
    return np.prod(np.array(iterable))

def multiply_functools(iterable):
    return functools.reduce(operator.mul, iterable)

def multiply_manual(iterable):
    prod = 1
    for x in iterable:
        prod *= x

    return prod

sizesToTest = [5, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000]

for size in sizesToTest:
    data = [1] * size

    timerNumpy = timeit.Timer(lambda: multiply_numpy(data))
    timerFunctools = timeit.Timer(lambda: multiply_functools(data))
    timerManual = timeit.Timer(lambda: multiply_manual(data))

    repeats = int(5e6 / size)
    resultNumpy = timerNumpy.timeit(repeats)
    resultFunctools = timerFunctools.timeit(repeats)
    resultManual = timerManual.timeit(repeats)
    print(f'Input size: {size:>7d} Repeats: {repeats:>8d}    Numpy: {resultNumpy:.3f}, Functools: {resultFunctools:.3f}, Manual: {resultManual:.3f}')
```

Results:

```
Input size:       5 Repeats:  1000000    Numpy: 4.670, Functools: 0.586, Manual: 0.459
Input size:      10 Repeats:   500000    Numpy: 2.443, Functools: 0.401, Manual: 0.321
Input size:     100 Repeats:    50000    Numpy: 0.505, Functools: 0.220, Manual: 0.197
Input size:    1000 Repeats:     5000    Numpy: 0.303, Functools: 0.207, Manual: 0.185
Input size:   10000 Repeats:      500    Numpy: 0.265, Functools: 0.194, Manual: 0.187
Input size:  100000 Repeats:       50    Numpy: 0.266, Functools: 0.198, Manual: 0.185
```

You can see that Numpy is quite a bit slower on smaller inputs, since it allocates an array before multiplication is performed. Also, watch out for the overflow in Numpy.

Comment: You could add the [eval way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39404394/281545) just out of curiosity

Comment: I suspect that `multiply_functools` and `multiply_numpy`  are weighed down by having to look up the `np`,`functools` and `operator` globals, followed by attribute lookups. Would you mind switching to locals? `_reduce=functools.reduce, `_mul=operator.mul` in the function signature then `return _reduce(_mul, iterable)` in the body, etc.

Comment: Also, the numpy version has to first convert the numbers to a numpy array; you'd normally already have made that conversion, to include that in the timings is not really fair. With the list converted to a numpy array once, the `np.prod()` option starts becomes fastest at 100 elements or more.

Answer (score 8):

`Numpy` has the `prod()` function that returns the product of a list, or in this case since it's numpy, it's the product of an array over a given axis:

```
import numpy
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = numpy.prod(a)
```

...or else you can just import `numpy.prod()`:

```
from numpy import prod
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = prod(a)
```

Answer (score 7):

I personally like this for a function that multiplies all elements of a generic list together:

```
def multiply(n):
    total = 1
    for i in range(0, len(n)):
        total *= n[i]
    print total
```

It's compact, uses simple things (a variable and a for loop), and feels intuitive to me (it looks like how I'd think of the problem, just take one, multiply it, then multiply by the next, and so on!)

Comment: Why not `for i in n:`, then `total *= i`? would not it be much simpler?

Answer (score 5):

The simple way is:

```
import numpy as np
np.exp(np.log(your_array).sum())
```

Comment: what about just `np.prod(your_Array)`

Comment: a) taking logs is expensive.  b) ill behaved for for zero and negative values..  could be fixed by using abs, and counting the negatives, and bailing if there is a zero either by checking in advance or by the exception.  regardless, it's expensive

Answer (score 3):

```
nums = str(tuple([1,2,3]))
mul_nums = nums.replace(',','*')
print(eval(mul_nums))
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. [answer]

Comment: I chime in and try to explain the code:
I personally like this code not much, since it uses eval, which interpretes the string as an argument or function (and is thus generally viewed as an unsafe thing to do, especially when handling input data). The line before that replaces every delimiting comma by a multiplicative `*`, such that eval will recognize this as a multiplicative. I wonder how the performance on this is, espcially in comparison to other solutions

Comment: Wow, such a bad idea!

Comment: [**Do not ever use `eval` (or `exec`) on data that could possibly come from outside the program in any form. It is a critical security risk. You allow the author of the data to run arbitrary code on your computer. It cannot easily be sandboxed, and proper sandboxing is harder than using a proper tool for the job.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 2):

Found this question today but I noticed that it does not have the case where there are `None`'s in the list. So, the complete solution would be:

```
from functools import reduce

a = [None, 1, 2, 3, None, 4]
print(reduce(lambda x, y: (x if x else 1) * (y if y else 1), a))
```

In the case of addition, we have:

```
print(reduce(lambda x, y: (x if x else 0) + (y if y else 0), a))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just wanna add a Python 3.8 One-liner answer:

```py
def multiply(l):
    return [b := 1, [b := b * a for a in l]][-1][-1]


print(multiply([2, 3, 8, 10]))
```

output:

```
480
```

explanation:

- `[b := 1,`  is for defining a temporary variable
- `...[b := b * a for a in l]` is for iterating over the list and multiplying `b` by every element
- `...[-1][-1]` is because the final list is `[b, [b * l[0], b * l[1], ..., b * l[-1]]]`. and so the element in the final position is the multiplication of all of the elements in the list.

Comment: The `:=` operator was added in 3.8, and this works in 3.8 and up. However, this is needlessly cryptic.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however, my solution isn't aiming to be efficient or pretty, the only reason for it is being a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

How about using recursion?

```
def multiply(lst):
    if len(lst) > 1:
        return multiply(lst[:-1])* lst[-1]
    else:
        return lst[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can use is `math.prod()`
For example:

```
import math
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(math.prod(arr))
```

Another way is `numpy.prod()`
This is another library to import

```
import numpy
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(numpy.prod(arr))
```

Answer (score -1):

There are many good answers in this thread. If you want to do multiply a list in actual production I recommend using standard numpy or math packages.

If you are just looking for a quick and dirty solution and you don’t want to import anything you can do this:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

def list_multiply(l):
    return eval('*'.join(map(str,l)))
    
print(list_multiply(l))
#Output: 720
```

`map(str,l)` converts each element in the list to a string. `join` combines each element into one string separated by the `*` symbol. `eval` converts the string back into a function that can evaluated.

Warning: `eval` is considered dangerous to use, especially if the program accepts user input because a user can potentially inject any function into the code and compromise your system.