# multiplication over a iteratable, is there no times(iterable)?

Tags: python, math, built-in

Pardon my low-tech question, but either I'm going insane, or this simply doesn't exist.
I get that you can do `5 * 5` and that will work, basic Python.
You can even do `operator.mul(5, 5)`. But why is there no helper function for multiplication over a `iterable`?

I'm surprised to find that `mul()` isn't a standard built-in, or at the very least being a reference to it in either of the two main docs you end up in searching for mathematical functions. But also that there's no helper function called `times(iterable)` *(or similar)* that takes a iterable as an argument, much like `sum()`. It would for instance be handy when calculating the area size of a image if the image size is given as a tuple/list.

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html
- [How can I multiply all items in a list together with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840379/how-can-i-multiply-all-items-in-a-list-together-with-python)

Am I blind or is there a reason for this?
Isn't multiplication used that much?

Comment: @roganjosh Seriously don't know why I didn't got that in any search result or in the SO "similar posts" when posting. I've gone through hundreds of pages. My bad obviously, but that's a bit strange.

Comment: "python product function" first search, first result :) Guess it just depends how you see the question in your head when searching

Comment: What's your first result if you search that term btw? I'm curious about whether my previous searches might have had a big impact on what I see compared to another Python user

Comment: @roganjosh Probably. I also didn't think it was called product. Went for `multiplication`, `times`, `multiply` and `iterable`. Should probably have covered this in grade school language classes heh :)

Comment: @roganjosh It points to: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html followed by https://lists.gt.net/python/dev/704781 (using your search term, mine got me no where near)

Comment: Perhaps you use `itertools` more than me :) I rarely search for the documentation because I don't use it often.