# Filtering for tuples from another list and extracting values

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am working on handling two lists of tuples and deducing results.

For example:

```
A = [('Hi','NNG'),('Good','VV'),...n]
B = [('Happy','VA',1.0),('Hi','NNG',0.5)...n]
```

First, I'd like to match the words between A and B.
       like 'Hi'='Happy' or 'Hi'='Hi'
Second, if they are same and match, then match word class.
        whether 'NNG'='NNG' or 'NNG'='VV'
Third, if all these steps match, then extract the number!
       like if A=[('Hi','NNG')] and B=('Hi','NNG',0.5)
       Extract 0.5

Lastly, I want to multiply all numbers from extraction.
There are more than 1,000 tuples in each A, B. So 'for' loop will be necessary to find out this process.

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: is there anything you tried yourself? How did that go?

Comment: What is wrong with the very basic code with 2 `for`s, an `if` and `break`?

Comment: I tried [x[0] for x in a]. But if i compare two lists, it didnt work.

Comment: @jpp these are not version specific questions. Please don't add the Python 3 tag.

Comment: Oh... i will keep in mind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use a `set` and (optionally) a dictionary. The benefit of this method is you also keep the key data to know where your values originated.

```
A = [('Hi','NNG'),('Good','VV')]
B = [('Happy','VA',1.0),('Hi','NNG',0.5)]

A_set = set(A)

res = {(i[0], i[1]): i[2] for i in B if (i[0], i[1]) in A_set}

res = list(res.values())
# [0.5]
```

To multiply all results in the list, see [How can I multiply all items in a list together with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840379/how-can-i-multiply-all-items-in-a-list-together-with-python)

**Explanation**

- Use a dictionary comprehension with `for i in B`. What this does is return a tuple of results iterating through each element of `B`.
- For example, when iterating the first element, you will find `i[0] = 'Happy', i[1] = 'VA', i[2] = 1.0`.
- Since we loop through the whole list, we construct a dictionary of results with tuple keys from the first 2 elements.
- Additionally, we add the criterion `(i[0], i[1]) in A_set` to filter as per required logic.

Comment: could you explain how this work; res = {(i[0], i[1]): i[2] for i in B if (i[0], i[1]) in A_set} in brief?

Comment: Thanks jpp!! Really last one haha:) In here, (i[0], i[1]): i[2]), you use ":"i[2] to separate this and if B and A_set are same, then use .values() to get the i[2]?

Comment: No, the is the *only* comparison: `if (i[0], i[1]) in A_set`. `for i in B` is separate logic. Read it as if it was English.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
A = [('Hi', 'NNG'), ('Good', 'VV')]
B = [('Happy', 'VA', 1.0), ('Hi', 'NNG', 0.5)]

print(', '.join(repr(j[2]) for i in A for j in B if i[0] == j[0] and i[1] == j[1]))
# 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Python is so high level that it feels like English. So, the following working solution can be written very easily with minimum experience:

```
A = [('Hi','NNG'),('Good','VV')]
B = [('Happy','VA',1.0),('Hi','NNG',0.5)]

tot = 1
for ia in A:
    for ib in B:
        if ia == ib[:2]:
            tot *= ib[2]
            break  # remove this line if multiple successful checks are possible
print(tot)  # -> 0.5
```

Answer (score -1):

`zip()` is your friend:

```
for tupA,tupB in zip(A,B):
    if tupA[:2] == tupB[:2] : print(tupB[2])
```

To use fancy pythonic list comprehension:

```
results = [tubB[2] for tubA,tubB in zip(A,B) if tubA[:2] == tubB[:2] ]
```

But... why do I have a sneaky feeling this isn't what you want to do?