# Difference of Product and Sum of Digits

Tags: python, python-3.x

The task is to find the difference in the products of the digits and sum of digits. For example, an input of `4 5 6` would give `105`. The issue I'm having is dealing with previous iterations. I know it has something to do with the indexes of the list but I'm having difficulty figuring it out. Here's my code:

```
# find the difference between the product of all digits and sum of all digits
nums = input()
nums = list(nums.split())

def findProduct():
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        int(nums[i]) *= int(nums[i+1])


findProduct()
```

Comment: What is the issue that you have with previous iterations?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning the product of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104782/returning-the-product-of-a-list). Also, [Get a list of numbers as input from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663306/get-a-list-of-numbers-as-input-from-the-user)

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: You can't assign to the result of a function call, so `int(nums[i]) *= int(nums[i+1])` is a syntax error.

Comment: @AMC Depends on the context. This was a [LeetCode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/subtract-the-product-and-sum-of-digits-of-an-integer/) just a few weeks ago and they use camelCase.

Comment: @HeapOverflow Alright then, I'll be ticked off at LeetCode instead ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a built-in function for the sum (it's called [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)), and for the product, multiplying all items in a list is an [answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13840379):

```
from functools import reduce

l = [4,5,6]

def findProduct(nums):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, nums) - sum(nums)

print (findProduct(l))
```

Since Python 3.8 there is a function [`math.prod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.prod) so it can be further reduced to

```
return math.prod(nums) - sum(nums)
```

(and it requires `import math` instead of `functools`).

<sup>`math.prod` tip comes courtesy of [Heap Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12671057)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You could use numpy:

```
import numpy as np

l = [4,5,6]

print(np.prod(l) - sum(l))
```

Answer (score 0):

[`math.prod`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html#math.prod) does what you want. Just feed the array into it:

```
def fn(array):
    return math.prod(array) - sum(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

- `numpy.prod()` multiplies all the numbers in an array.
- `sum()` adds all the numbers in an array.
- Instead of messing around with len, you can simply say, `for i in arrayName:` and get what are trying to get

Here's what I did:

```
import numpy as np
Num = input("Enter the number: ")
def getDifference(num):
    '''Takes an input of a number (as a string) and
       returns the difference between the sum and product
       of its digits'''
    numList = []
    for i in num:
        numList.append(int(i))
    Sum = sum(numlist)
    Product = np.prod(numList)
    Difference = abs(Product - Sum)
    return Difference
print(getDifference(Num))
```

This works as you want it to. Note that you could make this code much smaller, as:

```
import numpy as np
Num = input("Enter the number: ")
def getDifference(num):
    '''Takes an input of a number (as a string) and
       returns the difference between the sum and product
       of its digits'''
    numList = [int(i) for i in str(num)]
    return abs(np.prod(numList)-sum(numList))
print(getDifference(Num))
```