# create all possible combinations with multiple variants from list

Tags: python

Ok so the problem is as follows:

let's say I have a list like this `[12R,102A,102L,250L]` what I would want is a list of all possible combinations, however for only one combination/number. so for the example above, the output I would like is:

```
[12R,102A,250L]
[12R,102L,250L]
```

my actual problem is a lot more complex with many more sites. Thanks for your help

edit: after reading some comments I guess this is slightly unclear. I have 3 unique numbers here, [12, 102, and 250] and for some numbers, I have different variations, for example [102A, 102L]. what I need is a way to combine the different positions[12,102,250] and all possible variations within. just like the lists, I presented above. they are the only valid solutions. [12R] is not. neither is [12R,102A,102L,250L]. so far I have done this with nested loops, but I have a LOT of variation within these numbers, so I can't really do that anymore

ill edit this again: ok so it seems as though there is still some confusion so I might extend the point I made before. what I am dealing with there is DNA. 12R means the 12th position in the sequence was changed to an R. so the solution     [12R,102A,250L] means that the amino acid on position 12 is R, 102 is A 250 is L.

this is why a solution like [102L, 102R, 250L] is not usable, because the same position can not be occupied by 2 different amino acids.

thank you

Comment: Is it possible to have e.g. `[102A,12R,102L,250L]`, or it's given, that same numbers are always next to each other?

Comment: Wouid [12R] [12R,102A] also be valid outputs?

Comment: no, valid outputs are combinations at each point, like the lists I presented.

Comment: Are the values sorted into a predictable order?

Answer (score 0):

So it works with `["10A","100B","12C","100R"]` (case 1) and `['12R','102A','102L','250L']` (case 2)

```py
import itertools as it

liste = ['12R','102A','102L','250L']

comb = []
for e in it.combinations(range(4), 3):
    e1 = liste[e[0]][:-1]
    e2 = liste[e[1]][:-1]
    e3 = liste[e[2]][:-1]
    if e1 != e2 and e2 != e3 and e3 != e1:
        comb.append([e1+liste[e[0]][-1], e2+liste[e[1]][-1], e3+liste[e[2]][-1]])
print(list(comb))
# case 1 : [['10A', '100B', '12C'], ['10A', '12C', '100R']]
# case 2 : [['12R', '102A', '250L'], ['12R', '102L', '250L']]
```

Comment: can you guys please read the question before commenting. this is not what i need, is the example output i presented not clear?

Comment: I think "however for only one combination/number" is unclear.

Comment: I think so I believed you want all the possible combinations

Comment: the output i gave is the output i would want. so at each unique number i get all possible combinations. i guess i a way to solve this is with nested loops but i have hundreds of different variations, so that doesn't work

Comment: is it what you are looking for before I optimize the code ?

Comment: ['102A', '102L', '250L'], again no. it cant be the same position (102) multiple times. the only valid solutions are the 2 lists i posted in my original question. ['12R', '102A', '102L'] is wrong also

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
from itertools import groupby
import re

def __genComb(arr, res=[]):
    for i in range(len(res), len(arr)):
        el=arr[i]
        if(len(el[1])==1):
            res+=el[1]
        else:
            for el_2 in el[1]:
                yield from __genComb(arr, res+[el_2])
            break
    if(len(res)==len(arr)): yield res

def genComb(arr):
    res=[(k, list(v)) for k,v in groupby(sorted(arr), key=lambda x: re.match(r"(\d*)", x).group(1))]
    yield from __genComb(res)
```

Sample output (using the input you provided):

```py
test=["12R","102A","102L","250L"]

for el in genComb(test):
    print(el)

# returns:

['102A', '12R', '250L']
['102L', '12R', '250L']
```

Comment: hello, most of these are not valid, sorry. the only acceptable solutions are the 2 lists i posted above. i tried to edit the OP to make the question more clear

Comment: See now - I added one element to your input

Comment: (it mimics your desired output, when we take the input, which you provided)

Comment: Ok, tweaked my answer - so you have same input, as in your question ;)

Comment: hey, when i use a different list, for example test = ["10A","100B","12C","100R"] i get back ['12R', '100B', '12C', '100R']. it also doesn't work when i try it with my actual list, which is a lot larger

Comment: Ok - that's what I was asking about in the comment to the main question - order doesn't matter for the output then ?

Comment: I.e. `["10A","100B","12C","100R"]` should produce same as `["10A","100B","100R","12C"]` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive generator function:

```
from itertools import groupby as gb
import re

def combos(d, c = []):
  if not d:
     yield c
  else:
     for a, b in d[0]:
       yield from combos(d[1:], c + [a+b]) 

d = ['12R', '102A', '102L', '250L']
vals = [re.findall('^\d+|\w+$', i) for i in d]
new_d = [list(b) for _, b in gb(sorted(vals, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])]
print(list(combos(new_d)))
```

Output:

```
[['102A', '12R', '250L'], ['102L', '12R', '250L']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

def get_grouped_options(input):
     options = {}
     for option in input:
          m = re.match('([\d]+)([A-Z])$', option)
          if m:
               position = int(m.group(1))
               acid = m.group(2)
          else:
               continue
          if position not in options:
               options[position] = []
          options[position].append(acid)
     return options


def yield_all_combos(options):
     n = len(options)
     positions = list(options.keys())
     indices = [0] * n
     while True:
          yield ["{}{}".format(position, options[position][indices[i]])
                 for i, position in enumerate(positions)]
          j = 0
          indices[j] += 1
          while indices[j] == len(options[positions[j]]):
               # carry
               indices[j] = 0
               j += 1
               if j == n:
                    # overflow
                    return
               indices[j] += 1


input = ['12R', '102A', '102L', '250L']

options = get_grouped_options(input)

for combo in yield_all_combos(options):
     print("[{}]".format(",".join(combo)))
```

Gives:

```
[12R,102A,250L]
[12R,102L,250L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for!

This works by

- generating a collection of all the postfixes each prefix can have
- finding the total count of positions (multiply the length of each sublist together)
- rotating through each postfix by basing the read index off of both its member postfix position in the collection and the absolute result index (known location in final results)

```py
import collections
import functools
import operator
import re

# initial input
starting_values = ["12R","102A","102L","250L"]

d = collections.defaultdict(list)  # use a set if duplicates are possible
for value in starting_values:
    numeric, postfix = re.match(r"(\d+)(.*)", value).groups()
    d[numeric].append(postfix)  # .* matches ""; consider (postfix or "_") to give value a size

# d is now a dictionary of lists where each key is the prefix
# and each value is a list of possible postfixes


# each set of postfixes multiplies the total combinations by its length
total_combinations = functools.reduce(
    operator.mul,
    (len(sublist) for sublist in d.values())
)

results = collections.defaultdict(list)
for results_pos in range(total_combinations):
    for index, (prefix, postfix_set) in enumerate(d.items()):
        results[results_pos].append(
            "{}{}".format(  # recombine the values
                prefix,     # numeric prefix
                postfix_set[(results_pos + index) % len(postfix_set)]
            ))

# results is now a dictionary mapping { result index: unique list }
```

displaying

```py
# set width of column by longest prefix string
# need a collection for intermediate cols, but beyond scope of Q
col_width = max(len(str(k)) for k in results)
for k, v in results.items():
    print("{:<{w}}: {}".format(k, v, w=col_width))


0: ['12R', '102L', '250L']
1: ['12R', '102A', '250L']
```

with a more advanced input

```py
["12R","102A","102L","250L","1234","1234A","1234C"]

0: ['12R', '102L', '250L', '1234']
1: ['12R', '102A', '250L', '1234A']
2: ['12R', '102L', '250L', '1234C']
3: ['12R', '102A', '250L', '1234']
4: ['12R', '102L', '250L', '1234A']
5: ['12R', '102A', '250L', '1234C']
```

You can confirm the values are indeed unique with a `set`

```py
final = set(",".join(x) for x in results.values())
for f in final:
    print(f)

12R,102L,250L,1234
12R,102A,250L,1234A
12R,102L,250L,1234C
12R,102A,250L,1234
12R,102L,250L,1234A
12R,102A,250L,1234C
```

---

notes

- in cPython, regexes are cached after their first compile
- list member multiplier from ["How can I multiply all items in a list together with Python?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13840436/4541045)