# Multiplying all negative values in a list

Tags: python, list, multiplication

can someone help me write code in Python for this problem?

```
x = [10,-5,6,-7,2,4,-9,12,-55,33,44,77]
```

Write up some code to multiply only the negative values. Print the result of these multiplications. Include a loop of some kind as well as an if-statement to grab just the negative numbers.

This is what I have so far:

```
x = [10,-5,6,-7,2,4,-9,12,-55,33,44,77]

for num in x:
    if num < 0:
        print (num, end = "")
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I multiply all items in a list together with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840379/how-can-i-multiply-all-items-in-a-list-together-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, here's one way via [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html)

```
from functools import reduce
x = [10, -5, 6, -7, 2, 4, -9, 12, -55, 33, 44, 77, -1]

result = reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, (i for i in x if i < 0))
```

OUTPUT:

```
17325
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it. I think they want you to do a simple script:

```py
x = [10,-5,6,-7,2,4,-9,12,-55,33,44,77]

result = 1
for num in x:
    if num < 0:
        result = result * num
        # or result *= num

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

With basic arithmetic and closest to your original version:

```
total = 0 if len(x)==0 else 1

for i in x:
    if i < 0:
        total *= i

print(total, end = "")
```

---

```
17325
```

borrowing from https://stackoverflow.com/a/13843424/1248974