# Why is numpy.prod() incorrectly returning negative results, or 0, for my long lists of natural numbers?

Tags: python, numpy, math

I'm just working on Project Euler [problem 12](https://projecteuler.net/problem=12), so I need to do some testing against numbers that are multiples of over 500 unique factors.

I figured that the array [1, 2, 3... 500] would be a good starting point, since the product of that array is the lowest possible such number. However, numpy.prod() returns *zero* for this array. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but what the hell is it?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> array = []
>>> for i in range(1,100):
...   array.append(i)
... 
>>> np.prod(array)
0
>>> array.append(501)
>>> np.prod(array)
0
>>> array.append(5320934)
>>> np.prod(array)
0
```

Comment: Uhoh... numpy overflow ...

Comment: I seem to recall that Python int is variable number of bits or at the very least greater than 64 bits integers. So maybe try using a normal Python list with Python int datatype (slower and uses more memory but should fix your issue).

Comment: Related question - why does `np.array(array, dtype=np.object_).prod()` not work here either?

Comment: "since the product of that array is the lowest possible such number" You might want to rethink this. The actual solution is *much* smaller than `factorial(500)`.

Comment: Already with the product of 8 different prime numbers you will get 512 different factors.

Comment: Doesn't this mean your approach is wrong?  Project Euler shouldn't require hundred-digit numbers, should it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that [Python uses "unlimited" integers](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/105568), but in numpy everything is typed, and so it is a "C"-style (probably 64-bit) integer here. You're probably experiencing an overflow.

If you look at the documentation for [`numpy.prod`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html), you can see the `dtype` parameter:

> The type of the returned array, as well as of the accumulator in which the elements are multiplied.

There are a few things you can do:

1. Drop back to Python, and multiply using its "unlimited integers" (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104782/returning-the-product-of-a-list) for how to do so).
2. Consider whether you actually need to find the product of such huge numbers. Often, when you're working with the product of very small or very large numbers, you switch to sums of logarithms. As @WarrenWeckesser notes, this is obviously imprecise (it's not like taking the exponent at the end will give you the exact solution) - rather, it's used to gauge whether one product is growing faster than another.

Comment: Using `float`s will lose precision.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thanks for the correct note, I've updated the answer based on your point. I also think it's a bit of an XY problem here, as the question is *why* is such a huge product needed, so tried to add a bit on alternatives as well.

Comment: I should be more emphatic: *Don't* use `float`s for this problem! Any correct  solution will probably rely on performing *exact* arithmetic with integers.  With (big enough) `float`s, you won't get exact arithmetic.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser OK, thanks, I dropped the original first option.

Comment: Using logarithms will also introduce floating point imprecision.  (Sorry I'm being such a pest!)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser You're not being a pest :-) The thing with the logarithms is that it's an approach that is obviously imprecise. It's just used to gauge if one product is growing larger than another one. Nonetheless, will update that it's imprecise.

Answer (score 6):

Those numbers get very big, fast.

```
>>> np.prod(array[:25])
7034535277573963776
>>> np.prod(array[:26])
-1569523520172457984
>>> type(_)
numpy.int64
```

You're actually overflowing numpy's data type here, hence the wack results.  If you stick to python ints, you won't have overflow.

```
>>> import operator
>>> reduce(operator.mul, array, 1)
933262154439441526816992388562667004907159682643816214685929638952175999932299156089414639761565182862536979208272237582511852109168640000000000000000000000L
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the result 0 due to the large number of factors 2 in the product, there are more than 450 of those factors. Thus in a reduction modulo `2^64`, the result is zero.

Why the data type forces this reduction is explained in the other answers.

---

```
250+125+62+31+15+7+3+1 = 494 is the multiplicity of 2 in 500!
```

---

*added 12/2020:* or, in closer reading the question and its code,

```
49+24+12+6+3+1 = 95 as the multiplicity of 2 in 99!
```

which is the product of the first part of your list. Still enough binary zeros at the end of the number to fill all the bit positions of a 64bit integer. Just to compare, you get

```
19+3 = 22 factors of 5 in 99!
```

which is also the number of trailing zeros in the decimal expression of this factorial.