# Product of all the elements of a column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

For the following dataframe:

```
a= pd.DataFrame({'Interest': ['groupon','max','flip','dop','tap'],
                  'prime':[184711,60017,46271,1,23445]})
```

I need to find the product of the column 'prime'. Currently i am using this

```
a[['prime']].product(axis=0)
```

And the result is :

```
prime   -6420606569878898851
dtype: int64
```

Can someone explain why I am ending up with a negative number? Also i need to calculate product of similar large numbers. Need to find out the best way to do it without losing precision.

Comment: I think you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39089671/2901002)

Comment: Gotcha !!! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to cast the column as dtype `object`.  This way, pandas falls back on pythons operations and does what you want.

```
a.prime.astype(object).product()

12026137503830652765
```

Comment: Thanks....can i insert this number to a cell in my dataframe?? when i am trying to do so, it gives me overflow error