# Project Euler #8 : problem with the product of larger adjacent slices

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

Useful Links: [Project Euler #8, I don't understand where I'm going wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824570/project-euler-8-i-dont-understand-where-im-going-wrong)[Project Euler 8](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8)

My approach to the problem involves:

1) Starting from the first digit, slicing the integer into required slice lengths (13 here)

2) Creating a list of individual elements in a particular slice.

3) Evaluating the product of the digits in the list using numpy.

4) Appending the results of multiplication in a separate list.

5) Printing the maximum valued product from the list

Here is the attempt:

```py
import numpy
import math
i = 7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
i = str(i)
multiple_list = []
for j in range(len(i)-14):
    p = i[j:j+13]
    l = list(p)
    l = [int(x) for x in l]
    y = numpy.prod(l)
    multiple_list.append(y)
print(max(multiple_list))
```

The output of the above block of code is : 2091059712

Which of course is the wrong answer! Please help me in figuring out the reason for this discrepancy.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do and how is its current result incorrect?

Comment: I have run your code and got the exact answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. However, you really should not ask such a general question about solving a Project Euler problem--this goes against the philosophy of Project Euler. If you cannot solve a problem on your own, you should move on to another problem. It would be acceptable for you to ask for help with a particular line or concept in your code, but "Please suggest possible improvements in my code" is far too broad. Please narrow your question to a particular problem in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @ForceBru the edits have been implemented

Answer (score 0):

Why complicate your program? You can make it simpler -

```
s = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"

largest_product = 0

for i in range(0, len(s) - 13):
    product = 1
    for j in range(i, i + 13):
        product *= int(s[j: j + 1])
    if product > largest_product:
        largest_product = product

print(largest_product)
```

Comment: That works well! But why doesn't my code give the same result?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code doesn't work is because numpy uses 32 bits integers, like C. You are experiencing the same problem of the question you linked. You can find a complete explanation in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39089671
To solve your code you can use a for loop to multiply the 13 digits instead of using numpy.prod()

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it with a list comprehension:

```
from numpy import prod
n = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"
p = max(prod([int(d) for d in a]) for a in zip(*[n[i:] for i in range(13)]))
print(p)
```