# Histograms with a lot of dimensions in Python

Tags: python, numpy, bigdata, histogram

I'm doing a simulation of a stochastic many-body system, and currently I need to obtain a multidimensional probability distribution from generated data. For this purpose, I was trying to use `np.histogramdd` as in:

```
bins = np.linspace(start = -x_max, stop = x_max, num = n_bins)
hists = np.histogramdd(Data, bins = [bins] * dimensions, density = True)
```

However, this code produces a MemoryError (or throws an exception about some array being too large) already for `n_bins = 20`, `dimensions = 5` and `np.shape(Data) = (1000, 5)`, which is much lower than target values. Number of buckets grows exponentially with a number of dimensions, so it is easy to see why such problems arise. So, the question is: how can a histogram of large dimensional magnitude be generated, stored and worked with in Python? Are there any existing frameworks for this? Is it better to switch to something else?

Edit: MCEV and examples of error code.

```
x_max = 10 
n_bins = 20 
Data = np.random.uniform(-x_max, x_max, size=(1000, dimensions))

bins = np.linspace(start = -x_max, stop = x_max, num = n_bins)
hists = np.histogramdd(Data, bins = [bins] * dimensions, density = True)
```

Putting `dimensions = 7`, I get:

```
lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\histograms.py in histogramdd(sample, bins, range, normed, weights, density)
1066 # Compute the number of repetitions in xy and assign it to the
1067 # flattened histmat.
-> 1068  hist = np.bincount(xy, weights, minlength=nbin.prod())
MemoryError:
```

`dimensions = 15`:

```
   1062     # Compute the sample indices in the flattened histogram matrix.
   1063     # This raises an error if the array is too large.
-> 1064     xy = np.ravel_multi_index(Ncount, nbin)
   1065 
   1066     # Compute the number of repetitions in xy and assign it to the

ValueError: invalid dims: array size defined by dims is larger than the maximum possible size.
```

`dimensions = 10`

```
   1066     # Compute the number of repetitions in xy and assign it to the
   1067     # flattened histmat.
-> 1068     hist = np.bincount(xy, weights, minlength=nbin.prod())
   1069 
   1070     # Shape into a proper matrix

ValueError: 'minlength' must not be negative
```

Comment: Can you please add the error code to the question?

Comment: @amzon-ex done.

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? If I prefix your code by `x_max = 10; bins = 20; dimensions = 5; Data = np.random.uniform(-x_max, x_max, size=(1000, dimensions))`, I get no errors.

Comment: @Han-KwangNienhuys keeping all other variables the same, for dimensions = 7, I get error no. 1, for dimensions = 10, error no. 3, for dimensions = 15, error no. 2. I will edit the post to reflect this

Comment: How many samples do you actually have? Your histogram might not be valuable if it is not enough. Apart from that, you might need to work with a sparse histogram. So create a sparse matrix with n dimensions and fill it yourself.

Comment: @ypnos samples are generated from simulations, so there is an arbitrary number of them. The goal is to obtain the resulting probability distribution and to study it, so keeping the histogram intact is important

Comment: Why would you think that a sparse histogram is not 'intact'? With 20 bins and 5 dimensions you would need a good 3 mio samples to be able to _theoretically_ count up every bin. 7 dimensions and it is already over a billion. Sparse is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If the histogram has a fixed bin width on each axis, you can do your own book-keeping and use a low-memory datatype for the counts (for example 1 byte per bin). In the following example, the bins are the same for each axis, but you can adapt it for bin ranges that differ along the axes, as long as the bin edges are equidistant.

This code will not do range checking; you need to ensure that the histogram bins are wide enough to fit the data or you'll get an error.

```
import numpy as np

x_max = 10 
n_dim = 7
n_data = 100000
data = np.random.uniform(-x_max, x_max-0.01, size=(n_data, n_dim))

# assume bins are the same for all dimensions. Bin edges at x0+i*xstep.
n_bins = 5
x0 = -x_max
xstep = 2*x_max/n_bins

# high-dimensional histogram
hist = np.zeros((n_bins,)*n_dim, dtype=np.int8)

# build the histogram indices corresponding to the data samples.
ii = ((data - x0)*(1/xstep)).astype(np.int16) # shape (n_data, n_dim)

# increment the histogram bins. The np.add.at will correctly handle 
# bins that occur multiple times in the input.
np.add.at(hist, tuple(ii.T), 1)
```

But with `n_dim=8` or `9` you'll run out of memory on most systems anyway.

The question is what you're going to do with a histogram that has `10**10` bins; do you have 10**11 or more samples?

It's more practical to keep the `ii` array and generate lower-dimensional histograms when you need them. For example, if you want to reduce the 7D histogram to a 4D histogram on axes `0, 1, 5, 6`:

```
hist_4d = np.zeros((n_bins,)*4, dtype=np.int16)
np.add.at(hist_4d, tuple(ii[:, [0, 1, 5, 6]].T), 1)
```

Note: I recommend that you use signed integers for the bin counts. Integer overflows will be silent, but at least negative numbers in the bins will indicate that you had an overflow.

Answer (score 0):

In the third case, dims=10, you are getting an error due to overflow. A relevant thread is adding here:
[Why is numpy.prod() incorrectly returning negative results, or 0, for my long lists of natural numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39089618/why-is-numpy-prod-incorrectly-returning-negative-results-or-0-for-my-long-li)
This is specifically related to numpy.ndarray.prod(). You can either switch the product calculation back to default python way, instead of using the numpy.ndarray.prod(). But, for that you will have to edit the source code of histogram dd

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).