# numpy.prod returns negative value for list of all positive integers

Tags: python, numpy

I've completed Euler Project [problem #8](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8) (the answer is not included in this question), but ran into some unexpected behavior with `numpy.prod`. The function returned negative numbers for some list of all positive, single-digit integers. This looks related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39089618/why-is-numpy-prod-incorrectly-returning-negative-results-or-0-for-my-long-li).

```
import numpy as np

# this implementation doesn't work
np.prod(list(map(int, '9478851843858'))) 
Out[139]: -1817706496

# but these do
np.prod(np.array(list(map(int, '9478851843858'  )), dtype='int64'))
Out[141]: 2477260800

reduce((lambda x, y: x*y),list(map(int,list('9478851843858'))))
Out[144]: 2477260800
```

These are other examples:

```
 ('3975369781797', -514256656),
 ('9476545682848', -579076096),
 ('4765456828489', -579076096),
 ('7536978179778', -748460672),
 ('8694788518438', -1322254336),
 ('5397536978179', -1594459696),
 ('6652947654568', -1682231296),
 ('9478851843858', -1817706496)]
```

But not these:

```
 ('4788518438586', 1651507200),
 ('6978179778461', 1792336896),
 ('8787992724428', 1820786688),
 ('6947885184385', 1857945600),
 ('4355766896648', 1975599104),
 ('5576689664895', 2039787520),
 ('9194934969835', 2040733440),
 ('9878799272442', 2048385024),
 ('8617866458359', 2090188800),
 ('9781797784617', 2091059712)]
```

What about passing the python list to `np.prod` causes it to return a negative integer?

Comment: Specify explicitly a big enough `dtype`.

Comment: Actually I can't reproduce your result anyway (in numpy 1.13.3). But I'd be prepared to believe that for some version of numpy, it might see that the first data item is small and assign a short data type, which then overflows.

Comment: Cannot reproduce in https://jupyter.org/try either with numpy version 1.19.1.

Comment: np.__version__ ==   '1.16.5'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NumPy is written in C and C++, and it doesn't have the "unbounded" integer type that Python has. So all integers are of widths your CPU supports. This means that overflows and underflows can occur.

Take a look at this C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    int64_t data = 2477260800ULL;
    printf("i64: %lld, i32: %d\n", data, (int32_t)data);
}
```

And here's the output:

```
~> clang test.c
~> ./a.out
i64: 2477260800, i32: -1817706496
```

So it looks like your NumPy is using 32-bit signed integers that can't contain the unsigned number 2477260800 because `bin(2477260800) == '0b10010011101010000000000000000000'`, and that's a negative `int32_t`.