# How to find the maximum product of two elements in a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-itertools

I was trying out a problem on hackerrank contest for fun, and there came this question.
I used itertools for this, here is the code:

```
import itertools

l = []

for _ in range(int(input())):
    l.append(int(input()))


max = l[0] * l[len(l)-1]

for a,b in itertools.combinations(l,2):
    if max < (a*b):
        max = (a*b)
print(max)
```

Is their any other efficient way than this? As I am getting time out error on some test cases which I cant access (as its a small contest).

Comment: precompute `a*b` when max is not the max you'll save a few instructions.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre didnt get you clearly, could you elaborate please?

Comment: Don't you just need to find the two largest individual elements and multiply them? (and also the two lowest negative elements if you're allowing negative numbers)

Comment: @khelwood I thought about it, but in the question it is clearly written not to rely on that 'Keep in mind the answer is not always the product of the two biggest numbers.' but my main problem is why is this timing out!

Comment: @Maverick You can keep that in mind by checking for negative numbers as well. Otherwise you're writing an O(n^2) solution to an O(n) problem.

Comment: He means you do `a*b` twice.

Comment: @Maverick: that hint in the question is about the case where the answer is the product of the two most negative numbers.

Comment: time complexity of **itertools** is O(n^2)....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an implementation following @User_Targaryen's logic. [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/heapq.html) returns the 2 largest and 2 smallest numbers in the list, [`mul operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) returns the products of these 2 pairs of numbers, and `max` returns the largest of these 2 products.

```
>>> import heapq
>>> from operator import mul
>>> l = [2,40,600,3,-89,-899]
>>> max(mul(*heapq.nsmallest(2,l)),mul(*heapq.nlargest(2,l)))
80011
# -899*-89 = 80011
```

Comment: This is a good one, no time out, but still failing at one test case and do not know why.  Here is the link if anyone wants to try https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/arraysloops/challenges/arraysloops-4

Comment: @Maverick I've edited my answer slightly to use `mul` instead of the `lambda` syntax after reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104782/returning-the-product-of-a-list

Comment: You don't need to use `reduce`, try tuple unpacking: `max(mul(*heapq.nsmallest(2, l)), mul(*heapq.nlargest(2, l)))`. This heapq solution is faster than my sort based one for long lists.

Answer (score 14):

Iterate over the list and find the following:

Largest Positive number(a)

Second Largest Positive number(b)

Largest Negative number(c)

Second Largest Negative number(d)

Now, you will be able to figure out the maximum value upon multiplication, either `a*b` or `c*d`

Comment: Nice logic, I went with the answer which had heapq solution. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Just sort the list and select the largest of the products of the last 2 items in the list and the first 2 items in the list:

```
from operator import mul

numbers = [10, 20, 1, -11, 100, -12]
l = sorted(numbers)    # or sort in place with numbers.sort() if you don't mind mutating the list
max_product = max(mul(*l[:2]), mul(*l[-2:]))
```

This is a O(n log n) solution due to the sort. Someone else suggested a `heapq` solution which I found to be faster for lists longer than a few thousand random integers.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that heapq was appropriate for some test cases so had to tag it.  I liked your solution too, it was simpler.

Comment: @Maverick: no problem. They are basically equivalent, but heapq is slightly faster in some cases.

Comment: nice algorithm.