# How to multiply positions of a list of lists

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, list, numpy

How can I multiply this list with python:

```
A = [ [0.45, 0.89, 0.91],
      [0.5, 0.78, 0.55],
      [0.134, 0.571, 0.142] ]
```

How can I multiply every column, for the example 0.45*0.5*0.134 = 0.03015; 0.89*0.78*0.571 = 0.3961; 0,91*0.55*0.142 = 0.071071

```
 [0.03015,0.3961,0.071071]
```

How can i do that with python?

Comment: I'd create new lists using the item index with a for loop, then multiply all the items in a list, probably also using a for loop

Comment: relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104782/returning-the-product-of-a-list

Comment: Did one of the answers below help? If so, consider accepting (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 12):

You can do this in pure Python:

```
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce  # no need for this in Python 2.x

res = [reduce(mul, i) for i in zip(*A)]
```

Or you can use `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

res = np.prod(A, axis=0)

array([ 0.03015  ,  0.3963882,  0.071071 ])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use ***[zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)***,

```
In [5]: A = [[0.45, 0.89, 0.91], [0.5, 0.78, 0.55], [0.134, 0.571, 0.142]]

In [6]: [a*b*c for a,b,c in zip(*A)]
Out[6]: [0.030150000000000003, 0.39638819999999997, 0.071071]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use numpy:

```
import numpy
A = numpy.array([[0.45, 0.89, 0.91], [0.5, 0.78, 0.55], [0.134, 0.571, 0.142]])
result = numpy.product(A, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and list unpacking:

```
>>> [x*y*z for x, y, z in zip(*A)]
```