# Calculate product of an array efficiently

Tags: python, algorithm

As a part of a problem I have to multiply around `50000` numbers in list which are smaller than `10**18`.

I've optimized this by doing a divide and conquer approach

```
def multnum(niz,l,d):
    if(l==d):
        return niz[l]
    return multnum(niz,l,(l+d)//2)*multnum(niz,(l+d)//2+1,d)
```

However it still is slow, I'm wondering if there is anything I could do to improve the speed.

An example:

```
niz =[3,4,5,6]
print(multnum(niz,0,Len(niz)-1)) # Gives 360
```

The l and d variables are just helper variables.

Comment: You can probably use memoization

Comment: multiplication is fast, very fast.  Anything you do beyond having python simply go through the list and find the product, will slow things down because the overhead of calling functions recursively and splitting up the list is almost certainly going to be higher than the cost of just doing the multiplication.   See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104782/returning-the-product-of-a-list for some clever and efficient approaches.

Comment: Why not something like `np.prod(niz[l:d+1])`, I think this should be much faster, if working with an array

Comment: I agree with @yatu -- Using numpy and taking advantage of vectorization will be the most efficient method.

Comment: NumPy isn't designed for products this big. No NumPy dtype can handle this operation.

Comment: @DanFarrell The multnum function seems to be 10x times faster(according to my profiling) than the simple approach because multiplication is optimized when two numbers have the same number of digits.

Comment: It seems likely that you should be looking for higher-level algorithmic improvements than this.

Comment: It would have been helpful for the readers if you would have provided a minimal working example. Only God knows what is `niz` and `l` and `d` in your code

Comment: use the knowledge that a prod is the same as a sum of logs: `decimal.Decimal(np.sum(np.log(l))).exp()`

Comment: @jeremycg: The precision loss is unlikely to be acceptable.

Comment: @Bazingaa I'll add it in a min, anyway niz is the list of numbers l and d are just helper variables the left end and the right end. The function will be called with l=0 and d=Len(niz)-1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use numpy?

```
l = np.random.randint(1, 1000, size=50000)
%timeit np.prod(l)

# 39.9 µs ± 53.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

On the other hand, with python

```
ll = list(l)
%timeit multnum(ll, 0, 50000-1)
# 22.2 ms ± 108 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

So in this case numpy is around 500 times faster.

Comment: Okay, but now print the product and compare it to what you should have gotten.

Comment: Do u mean overflow issues?

Comment: Yes, it's going to overflow.

Comment: yes, to handle overflow numpy will be same speed as python.

Answer (score 0):

`math.fsum(np.log(niz))`, and then exponentiate --- or check if you can carry on working in the log space.

Answer (score -2):

I'm a little fuzzy on what l and d are denoting.Numpy has a built in package for this.

```
import numpy as np
np.prod(niz)
```