# Sum of indices over product containing indices

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I have to compute a sum over a product of indices (see equation attached). There are N sums for each of the indices (going to a for each index) and the product contains a function depending on a specific index (which I do not want to specify). I tried using a double loop

```
nlist = []
for i in range(a): 
    nlist.append([0])
    for k in range(N):
            nlist[i].append(k+1)
prod=1
result=0
for i in range(a):
    for k in range(0,N):
        prod = prod*f(nlist[i][k])
    result = result+prod
```

but I am completely not sure about the correct ordering and the way to correctly define the array `nlist[i][k]` such that the summation is correct.

[image: Equation]

Comment: What variable does your summation work over?

Comment: The code seems to be correct. What's the isse?

Comment: i should be the summation variable

Comment: The code is not self-contained (ie, N is not defined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your function can be applied to a numpy array, and letting your nk values be an (a, N) sized array, you can just apply the two operands together as `prod(1).sum()`, e.g.

```
import numpy as np
a = 10
N =3
nlist = np.repeat(np.arange(N), a).reshape((N ,a)).T  # [[0, 1, 2], [0,1,2], ...

f = lambda x: 2 * x + 1
result = f(nlist).prod(1).sum()
print(result)
>> 150
```

comparison:

```
prod = 1
result = 0
for i in range(a):
    prod  = 1
    for k in range(0,N):
        prod = prod*f(nlist[i][k])
    result = result+prod
print(result)
>> 150
```

Answer (score 1):

`prod` should be reset to 1 at the beginning of each product-iteration. The product should be kept nested below the summation.

```
result = 0
for i in range(a):
    prod = 1                       #  <<< begin at 1 on each iteration of i    
    for k in range(N):
        prod *= f(nlist[i][k])
    result += prod
```

A better way to do this may be to use a comprehension and the `sum` built-in function. This is arguably a more mathematical representation compared to loops.

```
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce, partial

product = partial(reduce, mul)   # let's define a handy lil' function    

result = sum(product(map(f, l)) for l in nlist)

# other variants
# sum(product(f(n_k) for n_k in l) for l in nlist)
# sum(reduce(mul, map(f, l)) for l in nlist)
```

If you're considering the NumPy module, you can use `np.prod`, [which is considerably faster over `reduce(mul, ...)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2105155/10239789).

```
import numpy as np
product = np.prod

result = ...
```