# Is there some type of loop for a product function of variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have developed a 5 and 10 cohort population growth code to establish equilibrium birth rates. Each of the cohorts are for different age groups, i.e. 0-14, 15-19, ....out to 55-99. I want to eventually expand to 100 1-year cohorts, however, it will be very tedious / almost impossible without a loop. There is a product relationship between each cohort that I would like to loop however, I've heard its hard to loop variables. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
       y10=(m9/k10)*y9
        y9=(k10/m9)*y10
        y8=(k+m9)/(m8)*(k10/m9)*y10
        y7=(k+m8)/(m7)*(k+m9)/(m8)*(k10/m9)*y10
        y6=(k+m7)/(m6)*(k+m8)/(m7)*(k+m9)/(m8)*(k10/m9)*y10
        y5=(k+m6)/(m5)*(k+m8)/(m7)*(k+m7)/(m6)*(k+m9)/(m8)*(k10/m9)*y10
```

..... and so on.

I want to basically code the relationship of last cohort (i.e. y100) * a product loop (not a sum loop) of i=1 to 99 ki+mi/(mi). Any help again is appreciated.

Comment: I am also a student so I apologize if some of this is rudimentary.

Comment: You should use lists more often, variables like `y10` and `m9` are tough to loop over.  You could instead use `y = [0]*10`, and assign to `y` with `y[0] = ...` if you do this with all 3 variables you will be able to loop over and calculate easily.  Before that, this might take thousands of lines to complete

Comment: Welcome to SO! Look into lists--this way, you have one variable `y` and you can index into each numerical value with `y[0]`, `y[1]`... `y[len(y)-1]`. Take the product with [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104782/returning-the-product-of-a-list/9114648).

Comment: It looks like `y[i]=((k+m[i+1])/m[i])*y[i+1]` for `i <= 8`.  Is that accurate?

Comment: There is way to do this with variables if needed using `eval` but I would not recommend it for this use case. As everyone else said you this is a good use of a python `list` or `tuple` though in particular this is great use for a `generator`.

Comment: I can write an example using a `generator` but is your example correct?  The first two examples don't match the pattern of the rest.

Comment: I would also need an example dataset to work with.

Comment: Hi all, the pattern expanded ends up being (k+m[i+1])/m[i])*y10 or y[last i] but if you write it out via a pi product function I believe the k[i]+m[i]/m[i] still holds true. Basically this step is just defining each cohort in relation to the last cohort so I can then use these variables with odeint to write each of their differential growth equations (also tedious but not as hard as they are all simply dy/dt= m(i-1)*y(i-1) -(mi)*y(i)-k(i)*y(i). For reference, k is death and m is maturation.

Comment: I don't have an example dataset as this is all theoretical at this point but that is the point of developing it down to 100 1-year cohorts so I can eventually read in census data. I'm happy to share the whole code if that would clarify.

Comment: A generator example would still be appreciated. Thanks!