# A product of numbers using list comprehension

Tags: python

I want to write this same code using list comprehension

```
mul_val = 1
for i in list_a:
    mul_val = mul_val * i
print(mul_val)


mul_val = 1
[mul_val = i*mul_val for i in list_a]
```

Comment: Syntax unformated

Comment: List comprehensions build lists, not single values, so they are of no use here.

Comment: list comprehension is more of 1-1 mapping

Comment: If you want a one-liner, consider [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce).

Comment: Starting with Python 3.8, there is a new `prod` function in `math`: `math.prod([1, 2, 3, 4])` returns 24.

Comment: List comprehensions build lists. Comprehension constructs, in general, are for expressing *mapping/filtering* operations on iterables which result in another iterable (a list comprehension produces a list). What you have here is a reduction operation. Your for-loop is a perfectly normal, pythonic way to do reduction operations. You could use functional programming `reduce`, but that's a style choice. It's very important not to think of list comprehensions as "one-line for loops". That is not what they are at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is `reduce`.
`reduce` is a really useful function for performing some computation on a list and returning the result.

```
from functools import reduce

list_a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, list_a))
```

**Output:** `120`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, you can use list comprehension in combination with [`numpy.prod`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html). The example is following:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> list_a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> [np.prod(list_a[:i]) for i in range(1, len(list_a) + 1)]
[1, 2, 6, 24, 120]
```

Answer (score -1):

The question seems wrongly framed, but from the code it looks like you want a product of all items in the list.

Use `numpy.prod(list1)` to get product of all elements in your list.

If you dont want to use numpy, there is a good solution(accepted answer) here: [Returning the product of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104782/returning-the-product-of-a-list)