# How to return the combinations of numbers in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have been trying to solve this python problem involving permutations. For example, this is what should happen when I call the function:

combinations(2, 3) ➞ 6

combinations(3, 7, 4) ➞ 84

combinations(2, 3, 4, 5) ➞ 120

I don't know why but when I call it (down below) it returns 2 for some reason. I know computers just follow instructions so there must be something wrong with my code. I don't know what though, please someone tell me! Thank you!

```
def combinations(*items):
    permu = []
    for i in range(0, len(items)):
        if i == 0:
            permu.append(items[i]*items[i+1])
        else:
            permu.append(items[i]*permu[i-1])

    return sum(permu)



print(combinations(1,2,3,4))
```

Comment: can you explain what `combinations` is supposed to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning the product of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104782/returning-the-product-of-a-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using python > 3.8 then you can simply use `math.prod`:

```
import math

def combinations(*items):
    return math.prod(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of all the numbers and loop through it.

```
def combinations(*items):
    mult_list = list(items)
    result = 1

    for mult in mult_list:
        result *= mult

    return result


print(combinations(2, 3, 4, 5))
```

Comment: `items` is already a `tuple` which is iterable. Converting it to a `list` is not neccessary.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the shortest solution I could come up with:

```py
def combinations(tuple_):
    exec(f'print({"*".join([str(n) for n in tuple_])})')


combinations((2, 3, 4, 5))
```

`exec()` basically interprets the given string as python code and executes it so in this case it prints out 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 because since they all are string then converting to python the string part "disappears" so they are integers again. (if You wanted them to be string You would have to explicitly declare that) it is also important to convert the integers in the tuple to string so that is why there is the list comprehension it creates a list of string n for every n in the tuple